# Get Product variant

Tags: magento-1.9, module, configurable-product

Hi i create module to send product to another server with `json` structure like this :

```
{
name: "Black Nolita Cami",
code: "877",
sku: "wbk002c",
price: "150.0000",
sale_price: "wbk002c",
discount: "",
quantity: "0.0000",
weight: null,
url: "black-nolita-cami.html"}
```

But i have another field `variants` that i have put all product's variants in there .
How to Do i it?